# How to do to the nth power in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a function that I need to handle in Javascript:

```
equipment * ((rate/12) / ((1-(1+(rate/12))^-term)))
```

How do I convert it (^) into Javascript?

This is what it looks like so far:

```
const calculation = equipment * ((rate / 12) / ((1 - (1 + (rate / 12)) - term)));
```

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript has an [operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Exponentiation) for it:

```js
console.log(3 ** 5);
```

Comment: I guess I just don't understand how to do this within this function equipment * ((rate/12) / ((1-(1+(rate/12))^-term)))

Comment: @MaxT Do you mean `equipment * ((rate/12) / ((1-(1+(rate/12))**-term)))`?

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:

```
let result = Math.pow(3, 5)
//or
let result = 3 ** 5
```

This is equivalent to `3^5`